# Create Azure WebJob for multiple entries of Dictionary object

Tags: c#, azure, web-applications, azure-webjobs, iot

Requirement: I will create Dictionary/List with about 5 item in it (Initially this will be static). I need to run some operations for each item in that List. Each item may have different running time (i.e. 3min, 5min)

Later from my Azure Web App user will be able to add some item to that List. I might update WebJob Dictionary/List using Azure Queue.

Any idea about how can i run individual process/timer task for each list item?

Answer (score 1):

You can put these items in an [Azure Storage Queue](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues/) and have a [WebJob that listens to that queue](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-queues-how-to/). Every time you insert a message into the queue, a job will be triggered. Though the question is pretty vague about the nature of that list and where the values come from etc.